# Sci-Fi cartoon series about animal versions of the Knights of the Round Table

Tags: story-identification, cartoon, animals, medieval

This cartoon is sci-fi (flying cars and laser pistols) in another world with medieval traditions (sword fighting and [charging against each other on a horse (jousting)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHwwZ.jpg)) where all the characters were  animals. The main character was a lion whose name I think was King Arthur. There was also Merlin who was experimenting on Arthur's sword because it was the answer to someone's poisoning.

I think it was made around 2010 but not sure about it. And it had the same style of animation as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1u0x.jpg) and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14BSh.jpg).

It's not *King Arthur and the Knights of Justice* or *Visionaries: Spectral Knights*.

Comment: Please take a look at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and answer as many questions as you can. :) It will help us help you.

Comment: Possibly the same one as at https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/26h4gc/tomtcartoon_anthropomorphic_lion_king_arthur_got/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/3b530z/tomt_cartoon_anthropomorphic_lion_version_of_king/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VNjhbOH8m2U?

Comment: @Valorum: Not anthropomorphic animals...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h0n-MvumN3Q?

Comment: Actual animals? Visionaries had blue spectral animals kinda erupting from the heroes chests; https://i.stack.imgur.com/lquSJ.png

Comment: Yes actual animals, not blue spectral animals

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Souds about right the 2 reddit links you shared

Comment: It's not king Arthur and the knights of Justice or Visionaries, spectral knights

Comment: Congrats on providing sufficient details to elicit an answer. :) And welcome to the site!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could it be *[Argai: the Prophecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argai:_The_Prophecy)*, a piece of French animation (originally released under the title of *Argaï: La prophétie*) from 2000?

[image: Promo image for Argai]

> The story is partly set in the year 1250, partly in 2075. Angel, the fiancée of Prince Argaï, is under the spell of the Dark Queen. This evil Queen steals the youth of young women and keeps them asleep for the rest of their lives. This way, she remains immortal. To save his fiancée, Argaï travels through time and meets detective Oscar Lightbulb, his assistant Barnaby and his secretary Moony Moon. They decide to help Argaï with his battle against the queen and the rescue of his beloved. To defeat the queen, they have to awake Angel with an antidote which contains 13 unique ingredients. Their first challenge is to find each of these ingredients.
>
> Unlike most stories involving time travel, when a character is killed in a time that is not their own, they are returned to their own time rather than dying. This is why it is necessary for the heroes to defeat Queen Orial in 2075 and for Queen Orial to kill Argaï in 1250, as it would not be permanent otherwise.

Here is the intro:

There don't seem to be explicit King Arthur references, but it's anthropomorphized animals, knights, and time travel. [TVTropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/WesternAnimation/ArgaiTheProphecy) says that Merlin shows up in the last episode.

I found it while searching for *cartoon lion knight*